# Run Cygwin script on shutdown or startup

Tags: windows, bash, cron, cygwin

I'm extremely new to Cygwin but I am somewhat comfortable in Linux (I can read man files fine).

I want to create a BASH script using Cygwin that deletes the files in a folder on the shutdown signal given by Windows.  If this can't be done, I also could try deleting the files in the same folder on startup.  I installed CRON but does CRON only works for scheduled tasks, rather than on 'signals'?  Answers would be nice but a general idea of how to proceed would be even better!

I can write the script.  I just don't know exactly how Cywgin interacts with the Windows OS in order to perform these procedures.

Another question, how do I run CRON on Windows startup?

If it matters, my O.S. is Windows 10 x64 running Cygwin.

Comment: "Another question, how do I run CRON on Windows startup?" There are multiple locations in windows where you can add it in startup. Just google for "how to add items to windows startup"...

Answer (score 3):

Cygwin.bat, a batch file which was installed under cygwin installation folder will give you hint of how to run cygwin script.

The script contains just:

```
C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i
```

to run the bash shell interactive.
Make a copy of Cygwin.bat with another name (Startup ?) and change last line in

```
bash --login  path_to_your_script_here
```

Put the bat file or a link to in in the Startup folder.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a good website/tutorial I can follow to properly use Cygwin.bat files?

Comment: @JordanElizaga All cygwin applications depends on the cygwin.dll, you need to set environment variables to run those applicatiins.

Answer (score 0):

Great thread over here: https://serverfault.com/questions/245945/autostart-cygwin-on-windows-boot-and-run-a-cygwin-command

tl;dr
you can put command directly:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin

bash -c "/usr/bin/whatever"
```